# What does lrwxrwxrwx (l...) stand for?

Tags: files, ls

I hope you doing good. Linux Directories contain some system files usually it's hard to detect if Linux doesn't have color-coding enabled or no extension/suffix with the file. We use **ls -l, ls -lah** command to see the file type and other properties. Output can be as shown below 
ls
-rwxrwxrwx          Its a file (-)
drwxrwxrwx          Its a directory (d)
lrwxrwxrwx          **What dose (l) stands for?**
I wanted to know all kind of files we can have inside Linux (on basis of -, d, l if more) and the list of characters we use to identify them.
Example 
- stands for files
d stands for directory
l **stands for what???**

Comment: Thank you so much. for this explanation.

Answer (score 1):

`l` stands for a symbolic link. It is an alias/another name to a file or directory else where.

For example, let say I have a file `myfile.txt` I can create a symbolic link to it and use it as a shortcut.

```
$ ln -s myfile.txt another_name_of_myfile.txt
$ ls -l
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 kygoh kygoh 10 Dec 19 21:39 another_name_of_myfile.txt -> myfile.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kygoh kygoh  0 Dec 19 21:38 myfile.txt
```

Notice that `myfile.txt` is a file and `another_name_of_myfile.txt` is a symbolic link to this file.

More reference you can see `man ln`. I also found a website on this topic: https://linuxhandbook.com/symbolic-link-linux/

Answer (score 1):

`-l` stands for a [symbolic
link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link). You can see what
all letters represent in [coreutils
manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#What-information-is-listed) or `info ls` in your terminal:

```
‘-’

    regular file 
‘b’

    block special file 
‘c’

    character special file 
‘C’

    high performance (“contiguous data”) file 
‘d’

    directory 
‘D’

    door (Solaris 2.5 and up) 
‘l’

    symbolic link 
‘M’

    off-line (“migrated”) file (Cray DMF) 
‘n’

    network special file (HP-UX) 
‘p’

    FIFO (named pipe) 
‘P’

    port (Solaris 10 and up) 
‘s’

    socket 
‘?’

    some other file type
```

Answer (score 0):

`l` means it is a [symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link), `ls` should also show you where the link is pointing to:

```
$ ls -l link_to_a
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 vtrefny vtrefny  1 19. pro 14.39 link_to_a -> a
```

Other possible file types are:

- `-` -- file
- `d` -- directory
- `c` -- character device
- `b` -- block device
- `p` -- pipe
- `l` -- symbolic link